# How to initialise an object from a string (class name) for string.Format params object array?

Tags: c#, reflection, initialization, string.format

My idea is to store text with *string.Format()* place holders {0}...{n} in a database. The place holder value types are stored in another database *field* called "Parameters" in a comma separated format (CSV).

An example of a text in a database:

> Sender: {0}
>   Address: {1}
>
> Receiver: {2}
>   Address: {3}

And the "Parameters" field contains:

> Company.FullName,
>   Company.Address.FullAddress,
>   Customer.FullName,
>   Customer.Address.FullAddress

I hope it is obvious that the "**Company**", "**Customer**" and "**Address**" represent classes. **FullName** and **FullAddress** reperesent *properties* that return a *string*. The "**Company**" and "**Customer**" *objects* are able to load correct **Address** on request.

I am considering to use "*params object[] params*" with the *string.Format()* to pass the values.

Now the question is how to load the correct objects and pass matching count of params to the **string.Format** method?

Requirements

1. The text in a database must be editable;
2. The place holder count might be changed (added or removed);
3. Each place holder has corresponding parameter in "*Parameters*" database field;
4. Each parameter represents a *class* name and its *property*. Subclasses could be called but they must be separated by a dot (.). Example: **Company.Address.FullAddress**;
5. Only required *object*(s) specific to the text in the database should be created or loaded. It is not a good idea to load bunch of object just in case;
6. It would be great if just one method could handle the task;
7. Use any pattern or patterns if there is any suitable one. Maybe the *Composite*, *Factory* or the *Builder* pattern perhaps?

As a solution I see:

1. Hard code the object(s) loading for each database record. This requires that the text with place holders cannot be changed. So this solution is not suitable for me.
2. Load the object(s) using *reflections* per parameter. This would be a good dynamic way to do it but how to load correct "**Address**" object with the Customer address info it? Customer object is created/loaded by its **CustomerId**.

So far I am this far:

```
    public string FillTemplate(int languageId, long templateTypeId, params object[] parameters)
    {
        string formatStringFromDb = LoadTemplateContentFromDb(languageId, templateTypeId);

        return string.Format(formatStringFromDb, parameters);
    }

    public object[] LoadTemplateParameter(int languageId, long templateTypeId)
    {
        string csvTemplateParameters = LoadTemplateParametersFromDb(languageId, templateTypeId);
        string[] stringParameters = csvTemplateParameters.Split(',');
        object[] templateParametersToReturn = new object[stringParameters.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringParameters.Length; i++)
        {
            // Split class name(s) and property
            string[] classAndPropertyNames = stringParameters[i].Split('.');

            // Initialise and add the object to the parameter object array
            templateParametersToReturn[i] = InitialiseParameterObject(classAndPropertyNames);
        }

        return templateParametersToReturn;
    }

    private static object InitialiseParameterObject(string[] classAndPropertyNames)
    {
        // Now what? How do I create new object(s) from a string?
        // To create a Customer or Company class an appropriate ID is needed.
        // How do I know which ID (Customer or Company)
        // do I need to provide in advance?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Thank you if could read this far. Even better if you got some ideas for me :)

PS. At the moment **LoadTemplateContentFromDb** and **LoadTemplateParametersFromDb** make two separate calls to the database but I will refactor it so that a whole template info is asked at once.

Comment: For me the following is not clear: Do you only have an `Address` instance and want to create `Customer` and `Company` instances from it, or do you already have instances of `Customer` and `Company`?

Comment: Basically Customer and Company do exist (or loadable by ID) and each has its own address instance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the object, and a string for it's properties, these methods i wrote for something else could help:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets an object property's value, recursively traversing it's properties if needed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="FrameObject">The object.</param>
/// <param name="PropertyString">The object property string.
/// Can be the property of a property. e.g. Position.X</param>
/// <returns>The value of this object's property.</returns>
private object GetObjectPropertyValue(Object FrameObject, string PropertyString)
{
    object Result = FrameObject;

    string[] Properties = PropertyString.Split('.');

    foreach (var Property in Properties)
    {
        Result = Result.GetType().GetProperty(Property).GetValue(Result, null);
    }

    return Result;
}

public Type GetObjectPropertyType(string ObjectName, string PropertyString)
{
    Object Result = GetObjectByName(ObjectName);

    string[] Properties = PropertyString.Split('.');

    foreach (var Property in Properties)
    {
        Result = Result.GetType().GetProperty(Property).GetValue(Result, null);
    }

    return Result.GetType();
}
```

For getting it into `string.Format()` you could use the above methods to go from an array of property strings, to the properties themselves. You'd then pass this as the final argument os `string.Format()`.